# Full bridge rectifier forward voltage definition

Tags: diodes, rectifier, bridge-rectifier

I am looking for an efficient way to rectify a 3–20V AC voltage (at  ≤2A) and am therefore looking at integrated full bridge rectifiers and discrete Schkottky diodes. In a [datasheet of a full bridge rectifier](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/cd-hd2xl.pdf) an “Instantaneous Forward Voltage” of typically 0.49V is stated. I do not find any information on whether this meant per diode, so will the total voltage drop be double that? If yes, why are integrated full bridges so much worse than discrete Schottky diodes (around 0.3V, e.g. CUHS20S30)?

Are there other methods of rectification I should consider? I found the [TIDA-00858](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-00858) reference layout, but four LM74670s would be by far the most expensive item on the BOM.

Comment: Broadcom had some super low Vf bridges and legs, but I’m not sure they would take 2 A. Standard bridge rectifier to get an aux voltage to drive a synchronous rectifier?

Comment: Good question. If that's per diode, then you can only operate one of the four diodes at 2A continuous given the 110°C/W thermal resistance. That is not the way bridges are usually specified.  At 125°C Tj there will also be a LOT of reverse leakage, many tens of mA, enough to impact the efficiency, though the forward drop will be lower. I would say that's not a suitable part for actual operation at 2A and maybe not even at 1A.

Comment: At low voltages under 5 volts Schottky diodes offer better efficiency than standard diodes but at these low voltages synchronous rectifiers are normally used. IF you were certain the AC voltage was closer to 20 then standard rectifiers are efficient enough. The forward voltage is per diode.

Comment: That's per diode. What are your requirements?. Load, Pmax $max including heatsink.. BTW 2A DC load implies 20A AC load @ 10% duty cycle

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Power won't be much more than 5W.. Thinking about it, maybe 1 A or 1.5 A would be enough. I wouldn't wanna go above 4$ total.

Comment: Not enuf details....  You expect low voltage loss which means for 10% drop the input current is 10X your load and your load at say 3Vrms or 5Vpk/1.5A x10 = 1/3 Ohm thus for 10% drop the linear R is 33 mOhms and you cant get a quad ideal FET diode rectifier for $4. You can do that at such low voltage high current. Try a different generator

Comment: Thanks for making that clear.. A different generator is not possible, unfortunately... If not $4, what can I get a quad ideal FET diode rectifier for? I only found the LM74670-Q1 solution, which would be around $8, are there other alternatives?